# ZIPArchive cannot open zip with excel inside

Tags: laravel, php-ziparchive, laravel-4.2

I currently work on a laravel project and I need to -in short- extract the zip file. I used the usual open function on ZipArchive function, and it worked, IF the files inside the zip is pictures ONLY. My zip is containing excel files and it return an error. I tried to echo the zip->open function but instead of "1"/TRUE result I got "19". Does it impossible to extract zip consists of files other than pictures in ZipArchive? Or the usage is different for other files?

Answer (score 0):

This function will help you ::

```
/**
 * @param string $pathToZipFile
 * @param string $extractTo
 */
function extractZipFiles($pathToZipFile, $extractTo)
{
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
    $zip->open($pathToZipFile);
    $zip->extractTo($extractTo);
    $zip->close();
}
```

Comment: The code is only working if the zip uploaded contains images only. I tried to upload zip containing excel files and it's not working. The returning error is "Invalid or uninitialized Zip object". I'm guessing it's because of failing to open the zip file.

Comment: @Mikuriin If you want to run that code any how, then you can put your excel file to one new folder instead of direct zipping it, and while un-archiving it works.

Comment: it doesn't work neither. I even try to put images in a folder and zip it. And it doesn't work too.